# Yet another java generics confusion

Tags: java, generics, collections

Let us have the following code:

```
public class TestGenerics {
    static <T> void mix(ArrayList<T> list, T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
        T item = list.get(0);
        t = item;
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(new Integer(3));

        mix(list, "hello world");
    }
}
```

In the output I get:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer
```

It's nonsense - we've just assigned `Integer` to `String` without getting `ClassCastException`! We can't write it like that:

```
String s = new Integer(3);
```

but this is what we have just done here.

Is it a bug or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case as `list` is an `ArrayList<Object>`, `T` is considered as an `Object` so you can see things as :

```
 static void mix(ArrayList<Object> list, Object t)
```

So you assigned an `Integer` to an `Object` (which was a `String` before).

```
Object obj = new Integer(3);
obj = "Hello"; //No CCE here
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of Object. One of the objects in the list is a String, the other is an Integer. `getClass` returns the *runtime* type of the object, not the static type. There is no casting involved here.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me as if `getClass()` returns the dynamic (runtime) type of an object, while generics deals only with static (compile-time) type information.

What you print on the console is the actual, dynamic types.

However, in your example code, `T` would be type `Object`, therefore `t = item` is a perfectly valid assignment.